# Creating an Anagram Tree Using Multiple Tree Structures in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have the following `tikz` code that draws four different trees.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
  \node {R}
    child { node {O}
      child { node {M}
        child { node {A} }
      }
      child { node {A}
        child { node {M} }
      }
    }
    child { node {M}
      child { node {O}
        child { node {A} }
      }
      child { node {A}
        child { node {O} }
      }
    }
    child { node {A}
      child { node {O}
        child { node {M} }
      }
      child { node {M}
        child { node {O} }
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
  \node {O}
    child { node {R}
      child { node {M}
        child { node {A} }
      }
      child { node {A}
        child { node {M} }
      }
    }
    child { node {M}
      child { node {R}
        child { node {A} }
      }
      child { node {A}
        child { node {R} }
      }
    }
    child { node {A}
      child { node {R}
        child { node {M} }
      }
      child { node {M}
        child { node {R} }
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
  \node {M}
    child { node {O}
      child { node {R}
        child { node {A} }
      }
      child { node {A}
        child { node {R} }
      }
    }
    child { node {R}
      child { node {O}
        child { node {A} }
      }
      child { node {A}
        child { node {O} }
      }
    }
    child { node {A}
      child { node {R}
        child { node {O} }
      }
      child { node {O}
        child { node {R} }
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
  \node {A}
    child { node {O}
      child { node {R}
        child { node {M} }
      }
      child { node {M}
        child { node {R} }
      }
    }
    child { node {R}
      child { node {O}
        child { node {M} }
      }
      child { node {M}
        child { node {O} }
      }
    }
    child { node {M}
      child { node {R}
        child { node {O} }
      }
      child { node {O}
        child { node {R} }
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In inglese, puoi dire:

I would like to use these trees as branches of a larger tree, starting from a label-less root node. The resulting tree should be an anagram of the word 'ROMA'.

Comment: Sorry, your code won't compile ...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, your question is not entirely clear. It will be of big help, if you provide a sketch of expected result.

So far I can only suggest to use `forest` package instead of `tikz` ( using it the code is much simpler and shorter) and show how to draw a tree where root node without content has four branches:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree = {l sep = 6mm,
                s sep = 2mm,
                }
[ , coordinate
    [R
        [?  [??]]
        [??  [?]]
    ]
    [O
        [M [A]]
        [A [M]]
    ]
   [M
        [O [A]]
        [A [O]]
   ]
   [A 
        [O  [M]]
        [M  [O]]
   ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is above tree composition what you after?

To insert correct letters into nodes I left to you.